# Alternative to @@remserver in TSQL

Tags: cross-database

Was hoping to use @@REMSERVER in the definition of a table valued function. But I see it is going away in next version of SQL Server.  Any ideas on how to use the identity of the remote [server\instance] to influence the resulting rowset?

e.g.
On server [MAIN]

```
create view dbo.PartitionedUsers as
Select * from ((Users u inner join Groups g on u.groupid = g.id) 
    inner join servermap s on s.id = g.serverid and s.servername = @@REMSERVER)
```

On server [GROUP1]

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Users as [MAIN].[catalog].[dbo].[PartitionedUsers]
```

On server [GROUP2]

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Users as [MAIN].[catalog].[dbo].[PartitionedUsers]
```

When evaluated on server GROUP1:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Users
```

would contain only rows pertaining to groups mapped to that server.  Similarly for other servers GROUP2, ..., GROUPN

ta